# C recursive makefile targets for different build types

Tags: c++, c, recursion, makefile

I am new to Makefiles and have been trying to get following working with little success. In my project each subdir has:

1. `Release/` dir with a makefile that builds object files into `./Release/Src/` and outputs a `dir.so` to `../Bin/` (1 for each dir)
2. `Debug/` dir with a makefile that build object files into `./Debug/Src/` and outputs a `dir.so` to `../Bin/` (1 for each dir)
3. `Src/` dir with source code from which Release or Debug is built

Currently the below Makefile seems to always builds `Release/` and not `Debug/`. I would like a way (or some equivalent) to run something like:

`make release` - which would recursively run make in the release folders OR
`make debug` - which would recursively run make in the debug folders

I would like to retain the recursive nature of the makefiles if possible here (I appreciate there is some dispute as to whether this is best practice).

Project structure:

```
├── Makefile
├── Bin
│   ├── *.so
├── dir1
│   ├── Src
│   │   ├── prog1.cpp
│   │   ├── prog2.cpp
│   ├── Debug
│   │   ├── makefile
│   │   ├── Src
│   │   |   ├── *.o
|   |   |   ├── *.d
│   ├── Release
│   │   ├── makefile
│   │   ├── Src
│   │   |   ├── *.o
|   |   |   ├── *.d
├── dir2
│   ├── Src
│   │   ├── prog1.cpp
│   │   ├── prog2.cpp
│   ├── Debug
│   │   ├── makefile
│   │   ├── Src
│   │   |   ├── *.o
|   |   |   ├── *.d
│   ├── Release
│   │   ├── makefile
│   │   ├── Src
│   │   |   ├── *.o
|   |   |   ├── *.d
```

Top level Makefile:

```
SUBDIRS := dir1 dir2 dir3 #...

DEBUG_DIRS := $(addsuffix /Debug,$(SUBDIRS))
RELEASE_DIRS := $(addsuffix /Release,$(SUBDIRS))
$(info $(RELEASE_DIRS))

.PHONY: debug release $(DEBUG_DIRS) $(RELEASE_DIRS) $(SUBDIRS)

debug: $(DEBUG_DIRS)
$(DEBUG_DIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@

release: $(RELEASE_DIRS)
$(RELEASE_DIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Comment: Did you try to run make with the option "-d" to see what it thinks it needs to do and why?

Comment: One problem you may encounter is that `make debug` and `make release` build the same `*.so` top-level targets. If it is the case it could be that after `make release` they are considered by make as up-to-date and that `make debug` has nothing left to do.

Comment: @Renaud Pacalet: really this is answer!

Comment: _"(I appreciate there is some dispute as to whether this is best practice)"_ ...you have in a way reproduced the situation which also haunts recursive makefiles: As @RenaudPacalet mentioned, you are building the same target from two (or more) distinct `make` invocations, separated in time but looking at the same files. As make only looks at timestamps and not the sources which targets were built from, it can't detect that a recent `*.so` wasn't built from debug sources as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling with different options, then what you need to do...

1. Produce different .so files such as Dir-debug.so and Dir-release.so.
2. Based on .o files found in different directories such as obj-debug/foo.o and obj-release/foo.o
3. Then you can create generic, nearly identical rules for building both obj-debug/%.o and obj-release/%.o
4. And after that, nearly identical rules for creating the shared libs.

Using GNU make patsubst() method (substitute) means you can fairly readily do something like this:

```
ALL_MY_SRC = $(shell find ${SRCDIR} -name "*.cpp" | sort)
DEBUG_OBJ = $patsubst(%.cpp, ${DEBUG_OBJDIR}/%.o, ${ALL_MY_SRC})
RELEASE_OBJ = $patsubst(%.cpp, ${RELEASE_OBJDIR}/%.o, ${ALL_MY_SRC})
```

Those might not be perfect. You might have to play with them a bit. But that should give you one variable with all the source and 1 each for the two sets of object lists. Then you can make a rule like:

```
${DEBUG_OBJDIR}/%.o: ${SRCDIR}/%.cpp
    g++ ...
```

Again, play with it.